# .NET TIFF file: RGB to CMYK conversion possible without a third party library?

Tags: c#, image, tiff

Following up my previous question: if and how would it be possible to take RGB based [TIFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_Image_File_Format) files and convert them over to CMYK with standard .NET (3.5) functionality?

Is that possible at all?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually there is a way using the System.Windows.Media.Imaging namespace 
which only seems to work properly with TIFFs at the moment (which is fine for me):

```
    Stream imageStream = new
        FileStream(@"C:\temp\mike4.jpg", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
    BitmapSource myBitmapSource = BitmapFrame.Create(imageStream);
    FormatConvertedBitmap newFormatedBitmapSource = new FormatConvertedBitmap();
    newFormatedBitmapSource.BeginInit();
    newFormatedBitmapSource.Source = myBitmapSource;
    newFormatedBitmapSource.DestinationFormat = PixelFormats.Cmyk32;
    newFormatedBitmapSource.EndInit();

    BitmapEncoder encoder = new TiffBitmapEncoder();
    encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(newFormatedBitmapSource));

    Stream cmykStream = new FileStream(@"C:\temp\mike4_CMYK.tif",

    FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write);
    encoder.Save(cmykStream);
    cmykStream.Close();
```

See "[Converting images from RGB to CMYK](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/0a4fecba-6212-4e72-9e10-7874c6327e7a/)", the answer by Calle Mellergardh.

Comment: The link to Connect is a 404.

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think that's possible using standard GDI+ wrappers (System.Drawing).
GDI+ only supports RGB. CMYK based images can be read by GDI+ (implicit conversion to RGB), but CMYK based images can't be written.

You might want to try something like [GraphicsMill](http://www.aurigma.com/Products/GraphicsMilldotNET/default.aspx), which supports CMYK.

Comment: CMYK support in GDI+ is iffy, at best, and something like CMYK with 16 bits per channel, for example, simply does **not** work